# How do I configure a kafka publisher within a liferay application?

Tags: apache-kafka, liferay, osgi, osgi-bundle, liferay-7

We have a big Liferay workspace project with a lot of OSGi modules. Now we came into a situation like an event-driven notification system.

1. The Liferay application should send events to the Kafka broker
2. A spring boot application should listen to those events and send out appropriate notifications

So the Liferay application act as a producer and the spring boot application as a consumer. The latter part is not a concern. I can find thousands of resources that will help me. But the first one is a headache now.

All over the internet, I haven't found a single piece of information where it explains how to configure a Liferay application as a Kafka producer. If someone could shed some light on that, it will be really helpful.

nb : I am a newbie to liferay world, basically I am a spring boot developer.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what are your specific problems? (e.g. check [ask]) Also: Did you try embedding Kafka so that it's running within Liferay, or do you access it through headless APIs in a different process? The way you phrase your question currently, you're asking for documentation. This is explicitly off-topic on stackoverflow - you might want to rephrase it to solve a specific problem (see [help/on-topic]) or come over to the Liferay community and ask there.

Comment: What kind of events do you want to listen to? The question is too brought to answer.